# Django: UpdateView, creating another previous image

Tags: python, django, file-upload

If I change something but not imagefield in template and send it, django creating same image with another name. f.e previous_imagename_{random_generated_letters}.jpg... . Django takes previous imagename and creating same imagefile with adding some generated shortcode to previous image.

If delete def save() in models it's working (not creating another one) but I need change image size before saving to database.

views.py

```
class Edit(UpdateView):
    model = User_data
    form_class = EditProfileFormExtra
    template_name = 'account/edit.html'
    slug_field = "slug"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('accounts:edit', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs['slug']})
```

models.py

```
class User_data(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_upload_path, default='default/profile_photo_default.jpg')
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            #Opening the uploaded image
            im = Image.open(self.image)

            if im.mode in ("RGBA", "P"): 
                im = im.convert("RGB")

            output = BytesIO()
            w, h = im.size

            #Resize/modify the image
            if w > 1000 or h > 1000:
                d = w//1000 if w >= h else h//1000
            else:
                d = 1

            #Resizing
            im = im.resize((w//d, h//d))

            #after modifications, save it to the output
            im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=100)
            output.seek(0)

            #change the imagefield value to be the newley modifed image value
            self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField', "%s.jpg" %self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(output), None)

        super(User_data,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and the workaround I found was to use [django-cleanup](https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/)

> The django-cleanup app automatically deletes files for FileField, ImageField and subclasses. When a FileField’s value is changed and the model is saved, the old file is deleted. When a model that has a FileField is deleted, the file is also deleted. A file that is set as the FileField’s default value will not be deleted.